# Where Should I put beans.xml content (Jdbc Connect with Spring-Eclipse Dynamic webapplication)

Tags: java, xml, eclipse, spring, spring-mvc

Hello I am new to Spring and I am developing a Dynamic web application with Eclipse Kepler and Spring mvc. I opened the project as dynamic web project. So I have web.xml and spring-servlet.xml configuration files. When I tried to connect mysql datadase with jdbc connector I saw that there are some new Spring configurations about the connection in a Beans.xml file.

So I have 3 xml configuraton files: web.xml, spring-srvlet.xml and Beans.xml. My question is :Can I put content of bean.xml in web.xml. or spring servlet.xml? And If I do that whic changes should I do in my controller java class that I am calling Beans.xml file in that class.

Eclipse Kepler,
Spring 3.2.4
Apache Tomcat 7

Any Help will de appreciated.

web.xml contents

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
      <web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
    xmlns:web="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd"
    id="WebApp_ID" version="2.5">
    <display-name>DomainYonetim</display-name>
    <welcome-file-list>
        <welcome-file>index.jsp</welcome-file>
    </welcome-file-list>

    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>spring</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>
            org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet
        </servlet-class>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>spring</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>*.html</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
</web-app>
```

spring-servlet.xml contents

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
      <beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns:p="http://www.springframework.org/schema/p"
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans

     http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd


      http://www.springframework.org/schema/context


      http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.0.xsd">

    <context:component-scan
        base-package="Ekle" />

         <bean id="dataSource" class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource">
         <property name="driverClassName" value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"/>
         <property name="url" value="jdbc:mysql://localhost/domain_yonetim"/>
         <property name="username" value="root"/>
         <property name="password" value=""/>
         </bean>
    <bean id="viewResolver"
        class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.UrlBasedViewResolver">
        <property name="viewClass"
            value="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.JstlView" />
        <property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/Ekle/" />
        <property name="suffix" value=".jsp" />
    </bean>
</beans>
```

Beans.xml contents:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
       <beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
      xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd ">

   <!-- Initialization for data source -->
   <bean id="dataSource" 
      class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource">
      <property name="driverClassName" value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"/>
      <property name="url" value="jdbc:mysql://localhost/domain_yonetim"/>
      <property name="username" value="root"/>
      <property name="password" value=""/>
   </bean>

   <!-- Definition for studentJDBCTemplate bean -->
   <bean id="domainJDBCTemplate" 
      class="Ekle.domainJDBCTemplate">
      <property name="dataSource"  ref="dataSource" />    
   </bean>

</beans>
```

And finally my Controller Class:

```
    package Ekle;

import java.util.List;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.ModelAttribute;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.ModelAndView;
import org.springframework.ui.ModelMap;
import org.springframework.context.ApplicationContext;
import org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext;


@Controller
public class DomainEkleController {


    @ModelAttribute("Domain")
    public Domain getDomain()
    {
        return new Domain();
    }


    @RequestMapping(value="/DomainEkle")
    public ModelAndView domainEkle() {

        String message = "Hello World, Spring 3.0!";
        ModelAndView domain_ekle= new ModelAndView("DomainEkle", "message", message);
        return domain_ekle;
    }




    @RequestMapping(value="/DomainEkle",method=RequestMethod.POST)
    public ModelAndView domain_eklendi_fonksiyon(@ModelAttribute("Domain")Domain domain, ModelMap model)
    {
        ApplicationContext context=new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("Beans.xml");
        DomainJDBCTemplate domainJDBCTemplate=(DomainJDBCTemplate)context.getBean("studentJDBCTempate");

        domainJDBCTemplate.listDomains();

        model.addAttribute("domain", domain.getDomain_adi());
        model.addAttribute("sunucu", domain.getSunucu_no());
        model.addAttribute("tarih", domain.getTarih());
        System.out.println(domain.getTarih()+"-"+domain.getDomain_adi());
        String message="Domain Kaydi Yapilmistir!";
        ModelAndView dm_eklendi=new ModelAndView("DomainEkle","message",message);


        return dm_eklendi;


    }

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add all your beans from beans.xml to spring-servlet.xml by using import as below.

```
<import resource="Beans.xml"/>
```

also I recommend you to rename this file to some meaningful name - db-context.xml(or something similar).

Also never use below code when you are using annotation configuration/ rather when your context is already built by spring mvc.

```
ApplicationContext context=new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("Beans.xml");
```

Instead use `@Autowired` annotation. You can also use `@Qualifier` annotation additionally to pick up correct bean. As below.

```
private DomainJDBCTemplate  domainJDBCTemplate;

    @Autowired
    @Qualifier("studentJDBCTempate")
    public void setDomainJDBCTemplate(DomainJDBCTemplate domainJDBCTemplate) {
        this.domainJDBCTemplate = domainJDBCTemplate;
    }
```

And your request processing method should use this template directly without building context again(Its useless to build context every time you hit the url!!!!) as below.

```
@RequestMapping(value="/DomainEkle",method=RequestMethod.POST)
    public ModelAndView domain_eklendi_fonksiyon(@ModelAttribute("Domain")Domain domain, ModelMap model)
    {
        this.domainJDBCTemplate.listDomains();

        model.addAttribute("domain", domain.getDomain_adi());
        model.addAttribute("sunucu", domain.getSunucu_no());
        model.addAttribute("tarih", domain.getTarih());
        System.out.println(domain.getTarih()+"-"+domain.getDomain_adi());
        String message="Domain Kaydi Yapilmistir!";
        ModelAndView dm_eklendi=new ModelAndView("DomainEkle","message",message);


        return dm_eklendi;


    }
```

Comment: Thanks for your your reply and additional information, it is really helpful, and I will read some articles about Spring dependency injection.

Comment: No problem, you'r always welcome. Please note that you can also use "ContextLoaderListener" to maintain application context and autowire will still work. If you need to access bean using getBean() method for some reason, you can make use of WebContextAware interface- But Try not to build context manually when in web application.

Answer (score 1):

Add   in your spring-servlet.xml file like below.

http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/spring-framework-reference/html/beans.html#beans-factory-xml-import

```
 <beans  
   --------------------------
   ------------------------------
   <import resource="classpath:Beans.xml" />

   <context:component-scan
        base-package="Ekle" />

 </beans>
```